# Sitemap generator finds only one page

Tags: html, xml, indexing, sitemap, google-search-console

I've tried to generate an *XML* sitemap from different sites ([XML-sitemaps](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/), [Seoutility](https://www.seoutility.com/tools/google-sitemap-generator/), [MrWebMaster](https://toolset.mrwebmaster.it/seo/sitemap-generator.html)) but they all create a one-page sitemap.

In other words, they can't find subdirectories into my website.

I've tried all `www.mydomain.online`, `mydomain.online`, `https://mydomain.online`, and `https://www.mydomain.online` *URLs*, but nothing changed.

I didn't implement *URL rewriting*, so my website structure is:

```
folder
|-----index.php
|-----something.inc.php
|-----subfolder1
      |-----index.php
      |-----somethingelse.inc.hp
|subfolder2
      |-----index.php
      |-----foo.inc.php
      |-----bar.inc.php
      |-----subfolder4
            |-----index.php
            |-----baz.inc.php
|subfolder3
      |-----index.php
```

and so on...

The problem is that even *Gooogle Search Console* indexing system does only find one page into my website (and that's why I decided to build a sitemap).

*Do I have to change something in my configuration or tell it to the generators in some ways to make them work?*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @JohnConde it seems to be more about XML and host than SEO (and there are a bunch of [questions about Sitemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sitemap) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com))

Answer (score 1):

My guesses:

- your site's rendering is javascript-based and you use no technic to emulate urls,
- your pages aren't linked with each other, beside of the startpage.

Without to see your site *in natura* it isn't possible to say more.

Comment: [This](https://www.typed.online) is my site... How can I link pages besides using links and buttons?

Comment: The bot and user should be able to reach from any page the startpage, and from the startpage any page through normal a href links. Buttons and onclick are not helpful in this context. A sitemap is not only a list of urls - it is created through crawling paths, where a bot clicks a link and moves to another page, then clicks next link and moves on. On your page any bot stacks on the startpage because of missing real interlinking.

Comment: I have all the necessary links but some of them are buttons with `onclick=" location.href='...' "` and some need the user to be logged in to appear. How can I make the crawler read them?

Comment: Furthermore, there are some normal links too... why can't the crawler find them?

Comment: no, on your startpage there is no single `normal` link. thats why.

Comment: Ah you're right... You can I make `onclick buttons` readable?